# c: invert string using recursion?

Tags: c, arrays, string, recursion, char

What is wrong in this function?

```
   void stringReverse (char stringa[])
    {
        if (stringa[0]!='\0')
        {
            return stringReverse(&stringa[1]);
            printf("%c", stringa[0]);
        }
    }
```

I have to write a function that invert a string (ex: "Hello" in "olleH") using recursion; the function has to receive a string (nothing else) and to print the character in the inverse order... i don't understand why what i write didn't print anything...

Comment: A `void` function returns ... well... nothing.

Comment: Look at those few lines: Will the `printf()` ever be reached?

Comment: Please avoid using tags in titles, i.e, don't prefix c questions with "c:" in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` returns a value from the function and performs no further statements in that scope. Have a think about where you want that statement to be...

Not answering in full because this sounds like homework!

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I was inlclined to make it a comment, but I also think different treatment is neccessary for homework answers. Better for people to think that to just be told in those circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciated the fact that you didn't solve my problem but you make me think over the error I committed, that's is definitely better!

Answer (score 1):

Just do not use return.
Use `stringReverse(&stringa[1]);` instead of 
`return stringReverse(&stringa[1]);`

Because, the 'return' statement is using for return a value. But your function is void type, that means it returns nothing, it doesn't need.